# What is the best way to cachce static data lookups with Spring 3.1, Mybatis 3 and ehcache?

Tags: spring-mvc, ehcache, mybatis

I followed the [recommendation](http://code.google.com/p/mybatis/wiki/Caches) on mybatis-ecache integration but I don't see any log statements from EhCacheCache.

Spring also has an [eh-cache](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-store-configuration-ehcache) integration, which at first glance looks simple to implement but I haven't seen it being fired in the logs either.

Ideally I'd like to setup the cache before the Rest call itself to save the roundtri[p to the backend webservice (which calls mybatis mappers). Is there a working example, a preferred approach with Spring ehCache over mybatis ehCache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our app uses to wars: webservices, ui. I cached the mybatis dataaccess in webservices layer using mybatis-cache, and added a spring-ehcache on the ui layer. That way the mybatis-cache acts as a first-level cache, reusuable for any other service, and spring-ehcache acts as a second level cachce for the front end.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning on DEBUG (or INFO) level logging for `org.springframework` in your logging config. It could be your log level is too high to see anything in the logs?

Creating a "hot cache" as its often referred to, is quite straight forward. Simply create a method in your REST controller that populates your cache (stored in a field) with an example request and then annotate that method with `@PostConstruct`. That method will then get triggered after the class has been instantiated by Spring.